# How to unselect a link using jquery

Tags: jquery

Its a bit difficult to explain, but i will try.

Whenever someone clicks on a anchor link, temporarly a dotted box appears around it.
For example, when you click on the stackoverflow logo over the top of this page, it 
is surrounded by a dotted line temporarily. Because the page gets refreshed, the dotted box goes away.

But with ajax, the link doesnt get refresh, hence the dotted box remains on it.
How to remove that dotted box. When you click somewhere on the page the dotted box goes away.
How to do it using *jquery* or any other way.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To un-select it you can trigger the `blur` event on the anchor element, for example:

```
$('a').click(function () {
  this.blur(); // or $(this).blur();
  //...  
});
```

[`element.blur()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Element.blur) will remove the keyboard focus from the current element.

Answer (score 11):

Don't use jQuery or JavaScript to fix this. You can remove it by using straight CSS. Just be careful as it is a **usability feature**:

In your CSS stylesheet (all elements):

```
/* Disable all focus styles */
:focus { outline: 0; }
```

In CSS (targeted link):

```
#mylink:focus { outline: 0; }
```

The problem with the `blur()` solutions is the focus rectangle flickers on then off immediately.

Comment: +1 Really nice approach, the only downside is that it wont work for IE `<=` 7 (and IE8 in compat mode)

Comment: @CMS you are totally right. What a bummer. I use this code a lot, and never bothered to check how it ran in IE. -1 for me :)

Comment: Nice one! Didn't know we could do this with only CSS.

Answer (score 4):

That box is the focus. You could try doing this:

```
$("#mylink").blur();
```

so:

```
$("#mylink").click(function() {
  $.ajax({...});
  $(this).blur();
  return false;
});
```